# replace apostrophe with null in VBA Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to update a field in an Access table that replaces apostrophes with null.

```vb
Dim strLimitRecordTable As String: strLimitRecordTable = Me.txtLimitRecordTable
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE " & strLimitRecordTable & " SET vCompanyMapped = replace(vCompanyMapped, ''', '') WHERE vCompanyMapped like '*'*';"
```

But I get this error:

> Syntax error in expression replace(vCompanyMapped, ''', '') WHERE
>   vCompanyMapped like '*'*';"

I have a feeling it has to do with replacing ''' with and empty string ''

What am I doing wrong here?

I have another query that works fine:

```vb
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [" & strLimitRecordTable & "] SET Domain = Mid([Email],InStr([Email],'@')+1,Len([Email])-InStr([Email],'@')) WHERE Email Like '*@*.*';"
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in two places. First change {like ' * ' * ';"}  to {like '*';"}   Then replace the {'''} with {"'"}    [Had to edit because translated your string so not as you had shown]

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I tried replacing {'''} with {"'"} but VBA treats that first quote as the ending of the statement and treats the apostrophe as the beginning of a comment

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Regarding {like '*';"} - I have it the way that I do because I want to make sure the field contains an apostrophe. Now that I think of it, I don't even need that WHERE clause

Comment: Yes, the embedded quotes can be a nuisance... here is the correct syntax:  "UPDATE " & strLimitRecordTable & " SET vCompanyMapped = Replace(vCompanyMapped, ""'"", """") WHERE ((vCompanyMapped Like ""*'*""));"   But, yes, I would get rid of the WHERE clause...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the ascii character for finding an apostrophe in this case I would recommend you try:

```
Dim strLimitRecordTable As String: strLimitRecordTable = 
Me.txtLimitRecordTable DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE " & strLimitRecordTable & " SET 
vCompanyMapped = replace(vCompanyMapped, chr(39),'') 
WHERE vCompanyMapped like '*'*';"
```

Often when I programmatically have to search for punctuation I find that it helps to use Ascii indicators.  It helps cause fewer errors.

Comment: Thank you, this was useful! I just had to add a parameter in your replace(): `replace(vCompanyMapped,Chr(39), '')` As I noted above, I didn't even need that WHERE clause that was causing the syntax error.

Comment: If you can recommend my answer with changes, then I get extra points :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to avoid this and most other troubles when concatenating SQL:

```
' Converts a value of any type to its string representation.
' The function can be concatenated into an SQL expression as is
' without any delimiters or leading/trailing white-space.
'
' Examples:
'   SQL = "Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]>" & CSql(12.5) & "And [DueDate]<" & CSql(Date) & ""
'   SQL -> Select * From TableTest Where [Amount]> 12.5 And [DueDate]< #2016/01/30 00:00:00#
'
'   SQL = "Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values (" & CSql(" ") & ")"
'   SQL -> Insert Into TableTest ( [Street] ) Values ( Null )
'
' Trims text variables for leading/trailing Space and secures single quotes.
' Replaces zero length strings with Null.
' Formats date/time variables as safe string expressions.
' Uses Str to format decimal values to string expressions.
' Returns Null for values that cannot be expressed with a string expression.
'
' 2016-01-30. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CSql( _
    ByVal Value As Variant) _
    As String

    Const vbLongLong    As Integer = 20
    Const SqlNull       As String = " Null"

    Dim Sql             As String
    Dim LongLong        As Integer

    #If Win32 Then
        LongLong = vbLongLong
    #End If
    #If Win64 Then
        LongLong = VBA.vbLongLong
    #End If

    Select Case VarType(Value)
        Case vbEmpty            '    0  Empty (uninitialized).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbNull             '    1  Null (no valid data).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbInteger          '    2  Integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbLong             '    3  Long integer.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbSingle           '    4  Single-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDouble           '    5  Double-precision floating-point number.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbCurrency         '    6  Currency.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbDate             '    7  Date.
            Sql = Format(Value, " \#yyyy\/mm\/dd hh\:nn\:ss\#")
        Case vbString           '    8  String.
            Sql = Replace(Trim(Value), "'", "''")
            If Sql = "" Then
                Sql = SqlNull
            Else
                Sql = " '" & Sql & "'"
            End If
        Case vbObject           '    9  Object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbError            '   10  Error.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbBoolean          '   11  Boolean.
            Sql = Str(Abs(Value))
        Case vbVariant          '   12  Variant (used only with arrays of variants).
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDataObject       '   13  A data access object.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbDecimal          '   14  Decimal.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbByte             '   17  Byte.
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case LongLong           '   20  LongLong integer (Valid on 64-bit platforms only).
            Sql = Str(Value)
        Case vbUserDefinedType  '   36  Variants that contain user-defined types.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case vbArray            ' 8192  Array.
            Sql = SqlNull
        Case Else               '       Should not happen.
            Sql = SqlNull
    End Select

    CSql = Sql & " "

End Function
```